# intuitively meaning of $\underbrace{M^{T}\quad T\quad M}_?$

Tags: linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

> I know what $M^{-1}TM$ intuitively means. Suppose $T$ is the transformation matrix related with $\{\beta_i\}$ basis and $M$ is the transition matrix from $\{\alpha_i\}$ to $\{\beta_i\}$ then  $$\underbrace{\left[M^{-1}\right]_\beta^\alpha\quad T\quad M_\alpha^\beta}_{\text{same transfromation matrix to $\{\alpha_i\}$ basis}}$$

So When even I saw any decomposition like that $M^{-1}TM$ then it give me the same intuition. But I was wondering is there also an intuitively meaning of

> $$\underbrace{M^{T}\quad T\quad M}_?$$

If any other meaning do exist include them. I want to see them also.

Comment: When $M$ is orthogonal, that would be much the same thing.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I knew that. I am looking for in general case

Comment: Let $B: V\times V\to \mathbb F$ be any quadratic form. Then for any basis $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ one can represent $B$ using the matrix $T_{\alpha\beta}:= B(v_{\alpha}, v_\beta)$. Then $M^T T M$ is what you get when you use a different basis to represent $B$.

Comment: @ArcticChar nice! I didn't know why I forgot that.

Comment: Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence